# How to animate a view like UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview

I want to animate a view like `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp`.

I don't know the exact way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:yourView cache:YES];
[yourView changeSomethingToThePositionOrWhatever];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];   
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];  
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

// Make your changes
// show and hide views


[UIView commitAnimations];
```

[also check docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html)